# Cómo se formula en MySQL el select siguiente?

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos

Tengo una tabla, que contiene los campos `a,b,c,d,e` y quiero que con una sola sentencia `select` pueda mostrar el resultado que coincida con los valores que ha introducido el usuario en un `input ( ValorIntroducidoA, ValorIntroducidoB, ValorIntroducidoC, ValorIntroducidoD, ValorIntroducidoE`).

```
SELECT ???? FROM MIBASEDEDATOS ??????
```

Comment: ¿Qué es `input`? ¿Qué son los valores introducidos exactamente? ¿Pueden haber valores a `null`?

Answer (score 3):

Usa la clausula WHERE

```
select * from tblPato 
 where a = 'ValorIntroducidoA' and 
       b = 'ValorIntroducidoB' and 
       c = 'ValorIntroducidoC' and 
       d = 'ValorIntroducidoD' and 
       e = 'ValorIntroducidoE';
```

puedes usar este [link](http://www.w3schools.com/Sql/sql_where.asp) de referencia

Answer (score 0):

Puedes realizar la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT * FROM nombreTabla WHERE a=ValorIntroducidoA 
                          AND b=ValorIntroducidoB 
                          AND c=ValorIntroducidoC 
                          AND d=ValorIntroducidoD 
                          AND e=ValorIntroducidoE;
```

Si lo que introdujeras fueran strings entonces tendrían que ir entre comillas simples `''`, por ejemplo `a='ValorIntroducidoA'`. En caso de que sean números entonces deberías dejarlo como la consulta anterior.

**Nota:** En el caso anterior indicaríamos la tabla si estuvieras dentro de la base de datos en el momento de ejecutar la consulta. En caso de que estuvieras de manera externa tendrías que indicar la tabla dentro de la base de datos que tu quieres mediante un punto. Así:

```
SELECT * FROM tuBaseDeDatos.nombreTabla WHERE a=ValorIntroducidoA 
                                        AND b=ValorIntroducidoB 
                                        AND c=ValorIntroducidoC 
                                        AND d=ValorIntroducidoD 
                                        AND e=ValorIntroducidoE
```

Comment: @rnd Corregido. Muchas gracias por el apunte. Se me fue la mano xD

Comment: @rnd Le puse también algo de formato ya que se veía bastante mal en una sola línea. Ahora creo que se ve mejor y por eso se me coló la coma xD

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM yourTabler
WHERE ValorIntroducidoA = a 
AND ValorIntroducidoB = b 
AND ValorIntroducidoC = c
AND ValorIntroducidoD = d 
AND ValorIntroducidoE
```

Answer (score 0):

si no sabes que datos compone una campo puedes usar esta consulta

```
SELECT * FROM table_name 
    WHERE campoA Like '%valor_Input%' AND 
          campoB Like '%Valor_Input%' ...
```

así la consulta busca las coincidencias que contiene el `input`.

Es decir si en el `input` escribes `hola` se buscara en dicho campo el valor del `input`

Answer (score -4):

```
SELECT a, b, c, d, e FROM nombre_tabla;
```

o

```
SELECT * FROM nombre_tabla;
```

en este caso no hay `Where` (condición) porque no la pides.

Comment: _resultado que coincida con los valores que ha introducido el usuario en un input._ eso suena bastante a condicion (`where`)...